# Wordpress login system

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication

I'm new in the WordPress. I'm creating template in WordPress using PHP.I would like to know how to integrate my own login page( which contain two boxes i.e, user name & password ) with WordPress login system.

Please anyone give a solution. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are building your own theme, you can [add a login area to your theme](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/281889). If you would rather use a plugin, there are several plugins which let you add a login area, such as [Sidebar Login](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/sidebar-login/) and [BM Custom Login](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/bm-custom-login/).

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered the opposite of what you're asking, integrating WordPress with your "php-pages"?

All you would have to do is add the Loop to your "php-pages".

http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop

http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop_in_Action

Here are a few more resources:

http://www.jonathanwold.com/tutorials/wordpress_integration/

http://mattread.com/archives/2005/04/wordpress-is-not-php/