# WordPress Login System (with the loop?)

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I currently have a MySQL database from my old site that used to have a basic PHP log-in form and it would query a table containing the user information to log them in. Basic stuff. However I've recently moved to WordPress and it appears to be quite overwhelming at first, so I'm struggling to understand how to integrate my old log-in form with a WordPress site.

I have tried looking at this post:
[Wordpress login system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2443155/wordpress-login-system) and I am still confused. I understand the 'loop' is responsible for displaying multiple 'Posts' on a single page. But to integrate my own PHP code or more specifically; a log-in page, would I make a logged-in 'Post' and a not-logged-in 'Post', and perhaps use a template to display one or the other for a single page via a 'Loop' that uses an if statement to check if the user is logged in?

Or is there some easier method that I'm completely missing?

Thanks!

EDIT: I've thought about creating two pages, both using a template to check if the user is logged in at the top, and display relevant content if they are, or redirect to the log-in page if they aren't. Would this work?

The other possible method I could think of is creating two Posts and displaying the relevant one on a single Page via The Loop. Would this be possible? Are there any security concerns?

EDIT2: I'm going to try the Members plugin and see if I can modify the WordPress MySQL tables to allow room for my previous data.

EDIT3: I need to sync my user logins to our external database as it contains flags to check whether my members are able to access our 'support' pages. I'm not sure how this would be viable while relying on the normal WordPress login system and tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Keep it simple stupid.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)

The point of WordPress is to make things easier. So if you want to go with WP, you should adopt the WP way of doing things.

As comments has suggested, import your current user table into WP. Should be simple enough to change the columns around to get a working import directly into the WP users table.

If there is extra information in your current user table, simple create new fields in the User Profile section of WP. There should be plugins for this (although I have not tried any), but it is quite simple to add these fields yourself, just google for it, there are many tutorials.

For a frontend page to be accessed by only logged in users, simple create a [page template](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/page-templates/) and check if user is logged in with [is_user_logged_in()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_user_logged_in).

For the access part (Support Pages), either create different [user roles](https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities) and check that the currently logged in user is of the correct role. Or you could also add a custom user [capability](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_user_can) and validate it on your support pages.

Comment: To be honest I think I am over complicating things more than necessary as you say. I've been using and now grasped the basics of the WP log-in system and wish to adopt it. The only problem is that when a user registers with WP, the additional registration fields (added through Ultimate Member plugin) they get sent to the wp_usermeta table, rather than the wp_users table. This kind of complicates things too.

Comment: I'm now creating my own plugin that hooks onto the actions that the Ultimate Member plugin provides, thereby adding my own functions to be executed at the same time. This is the closest answer to my question so I'll mark it as correct!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the very general details you have given there is no 'easier method' you are missing. We can't help you form the requirements of your application, but we can help with code if you paste examples of the code you are using, what you are trying to achieve, and what is going wrong with it. Pick one thing, try it out, and if it doesn't work and you get stuck then post it here.

Comment: Would it be possible to create two 'Post' pages and simply use a template file to say "if SESSION['isloggedin'] { display login Post } else { display not-logged in Post }, on a single page? EDIT: I'll go give it a try. EDIT2: Would there be any security issues here? I.e. could someone access the logged-in post without logging in?

Comment: @vard I had considered this but wondered; would this be able to integrate with my existing MySQL database with user logins? And does it allow basic users (no admin/modification of my site, simply viewing pages they are allowed access to)?

Comment: @Ridai So you're trying to use two separate user system? The default wordpress one and yours? If so It could mess a lot of stuff, you should consider import your existing users to wp_users and send an email to users so they can pick a new password.

Comment: @vard Yes, as I wasn't sure if I could disable the admin features for one set of users (customers for example) and leave admin features on for developers of the site (me). I tried Googling this but couldn't find much information on how to do this.

Comment: @Ridai If you register your users as suscribers, they have only access to their profile - so they can't access any admin functionalities. More reading about WP roles: https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities